# Making apk from jar using microemulator

Tags: java, jar, apk, lwuit

Well i `ve made an app using java me and as graphics i used lwuit library which i added into the midlet`s jar. On Nokia it runs smooth and i wanted to port it to android. So i found out about microemulator http://microemu.blogspot.ro/2008/11/running-java-me-applications-on-android.html and i followed those steps and i got the apk. However when i run it into the Android Emulator it closes at start. I don`t know what may be the problem because i was able to convert the demo jar app into apk and it ran succesfuly.
Any ideas on what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you port your application to [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) which should be pretty simple. It has proper Android support which will make your application look and act native on Android.

Comment: well thank you for telling me about it, i was always asking myself if there was such a platform.